# How to query mysql command with php? Is this syntax correct?

Tags: php, mysql, database

I am trying to run this code:

```
$query = "INSERT INTO products_configurations (product_id, cuts) 
VALUES (SELECT pro.id FROM pages AS p
JOIN products AS pro ON pro.page_id = p.id WHERE p.id = $pageid, $combination)";
```

But I am getting an error.

For more information, the variables values are:

```
$pageid = 21605
$combination = "40 - Red"
```

This is the error I am getting (broken line for easier reading):

> You have an error in your SQL syntax;
>   check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near
>   'SELECT pro.id FROM pages AS p
>   JOIN products AS pro ON pro.page_id = p.id WHERE p' at line 1

***EDIT:***

I am using this code in order to insert to `product_id` a value from another table and it works:

```
$query = "INSERT INTO products_configurations (product_id)
(SELECT pro.id FROM pages AS p JOIN products AS pro ON pro.page_id = p.id WHERE p.id = $pageid)";
```

Comment: Thats invalid SQL, period. What should `WHERE p.id = 21605, 40 - Red` mean?

Comment: The query will generated something like this:- `WHERE p.id = 21605, 40 - Red` which is invalid

Comment: echo $query out before you try to execute it - I'm sure you'll see the problem. Copy and paste the line you're given into mysql to prove.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$query = "INSERT INTO products_configurations (product_id, cuts) 
VALUES ((SELECT pro.id FROM pages AS p
JOIN products AS pro ON pro.page_id = p.id WHERE p.id = $pageid), \"$combination\");";
```

check this out

Comment: _$combination_ => _\"$combination\"_ and _SELECT pro......_ => _(SELECT pro......)_. Just quotation marks and parentheses.

Answer (score 0):

```
$query = "INSERT INTO products_configurations (product_id, cuts) 
((SELECT pro.id FROM pages AS p
 JOIN products AS pro ON pro.page_id = p.id WHERE p.id = $pageid), 
 \"$combination\");";
```

Do not use VALUES in insert by SELECT query;